# When assigning Clipboard I get the error "varible name contains an illegal character"

Tags: variables, autohotkey, clipboard, invalid-characters

I'm trying to set the clipboard to a string but the string has characters causing the "varible name contains an illegal character" error. I'm not sure how I'm suppose to go about this error and I can't find any solutions.

My code:

```
var := "/text ~10 ~2 ~3 text:text"
Clipboard := %var%
Send, ^v
```

I expect it to paste "/text ~10 ~2 ~3 text:text" into a text editor, instead I get the error.

Comment: Hey there, just replace `Clipboard := %var%` with `Clipboard := var`. You don't need to enclose variables with percent symbols when using the walrus operator (`:=`), only when you're using the legacy method, which uses the equal sign operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names in an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) are not enclosed in percent signs.

```
var := "/text ~10 ~2 ~3 text:text"
Clipboard := var
Send, ^v
```

or

```
Clipboard := "/text ~10 ~2 ~3 text:text"
Send, ^v
```